# Como inserir uma linha vertical em um gráfico de barras ou pontos?

Tags: ggplot2, r, gráfico

Como poderia inserir linha na vertical escolhendo a posição desejada como no gráfico abaixo?

Segue o comando gráfico e uma imagem ilustrando o desejado.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(gridExtra)

dt <- data.frame(periodo = c ("junho", "julho", "agosto"), 
             peso = c(1, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3),  
             atr = c(0.95, 0.5, 0.7, 0.75, 0.6, 0.8))
dt$grupo <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = nrow(dt)/2)
dt$periodo <- factor(dt$periodo, levels = c("junho", "julho", "agosto"))
g_col <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = peso, fill = grupo)) +
geom_col(position = "dodge")
g_point <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = atr, colour = grupo, group = 
grupo)) +
geom_point() +
geom_line()
grid.arrange(g_point, g_col, nrow = 2)
```

[image: exemplo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta acrescentar `geom_vline` a cada gráfico. Mas é preciso ter atenção à interceção `x`.

- No gráfico de barras é imediato, a abcissa entre as barras 1 e 2 é 1.5;
- no gráfico de linhas, deverá ser entre os pontos de abcissa 1 e 2 mas mais chegado para o 2.

O código completo é o seguinte.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

g_col <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = peso, fill = grupo)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5, linetype = "dashed")

g_point <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = atr, colour = grupo, group = grupo)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.85, linetype = "dashed")

grid.arrange(g_point, g_col, nrow = 2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]